# jquery - get selected dropdown value on document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I want to loop through my page and find every dropdown menu with a specific ID. I have no problem accessing the options collection of a dropdown but not the default selected value when the page first loads.

I have this dropdown which is in a loop:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.InterviewSchedules[location.InterviewDates.IndexOf(date)].ChairId, new SelectList(ChairList, "InterviewerId", "FullDetails"), new {id = "ddlInterviewer" })
```

Here is my js which is in an external script:

```
 $("#InterviewManagementFrm #ddlInterviewer > option").each(function () {
        var lastChar = this.text.substr(this.text.length - 1);
        if (lastChar == 'A') {
            $(this).addClass("AcceptedPreference");
            //            this.text = this.text.slice(0, this.text.length - 1);
        }
        else if (lastChar == 'P') {
            $(this).addClass("PreferredPreference");
            //            this.text = this.text.slice(0, this.text.length - 1);
        }
    });
```

I want to add a class to every dropdown item on the page. The addClass is used to stylize the dropdown item with a different color.

[image]

In my screenshot only unselected items have a color. That's because of the javascript adding the class. I want to add a class to the values that are selected by default on page load.

Comment: Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

Comment: _"every dropdown menu with a specific ID"_ - Element ids must be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:selected` http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

```
$("#InterviewManagementFrm #ddlInterviewer > option").each(function () {
    var lastChar = this.text.substr(this.text.length - 1);
    if (lastChar == 'A') {
        if( $(this).is(':selected') ) {
            // add class
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("AcceptedPreference");
        }
    }
    else if (lastChar == 'P') {
        if( $(this).is(':selected') ) {
            // add class
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("PreferredPreference");
        }
    }
});
```

You can also directly target the selected

```
$("#InterviewManagementFrm #ddlInterviewer > option:selected")
```

if `#ddlInterviewer` is the id of the select then you don't need `>` also ID should be unique

Comment: Thanks I can select the selected item but now I can't assign my class to it. If I can get that to work then all the code works. I want to add a class based on the last character. If it's A then yellow background. If P then green background.

Comment: In your original code, you already have tests for the last char. My solution has provided you a way to test if the current option is selected. So where are you having the issue?

Comment: True. $(this).css("AcceptedPreference"); doesn't work for if ($(this).is(':selected')) {

Comment: @Sorry-Im-a-N00b you mean the code he had before for detecting character is incorrect? My assumption was that it worked and he just needed to know how to detect the currently selected

Comment: @nickgowdy I updated the answer, does it work for you? `$(this).css("AcceptedPreference")` is this a typo?

Comment: I ended up using your code and I wrote a bit more of my own for the onchange event of the dropdowns.